How to test an actual service in junit, not a mock of it? Autowired doesnt work
If you have a spring boot service, how can you test it?
You can write unite tests, but this doesnt work:
public class myServicetest() {

   @Autowired
   private MyService myservice;

   @Test
   public void myTest() {
       myService.myMethod()
}

I'm guessing that when you run the actual application, spring will do all the @Autowired injections.  Im guessing that junit doesnt know anything about spring.  Does this mean you cant tests spring services (not a mock version)?
I also tried this:
@Test
public void myTest() {
       MyService myService = new MyServiceImpl();
       myService.myMethod()
}

But this doesnt work either, presumably because MyService also has several injections, and uses feign.
Is using junit to test actual service code the wrong strategy?  What are the other options?  May be:

Provide spring configuration around the unit test some how.
Write a new main?  The current main does this:   {SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);} not sure how we could get it to call my test class (no entry point)
Create a web based API to call test class on the running server. I want to avoid this if possible, partly because it takes a long time to start the service, and partly because security wont allow any APIs on the backend services (the are triggered by kafka or database events etc)


you have to use @SpringBootTest annotation in your test class. more infos see here  https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web
